# Add Custom label in JSQViewMessageViewController iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I want to add a custom label (with a time stamp) in each cell as well as an image (for warning message) in JSQMessageViewController. I am already using bottomlabel as well as toplabel. But I am unable to get the result I want. 
[The image is a reference of what I would like it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qvf0.png)

[image: Reference image]

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *bubbleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Commentbox_right.png"];
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(textFrame.origin.x-2, textFrame.origin.y-2, textFrame.size.width+4 , textFrame.size.height+7)];
        imgView.image= [bubbleImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:bubbleImage.size.width/2-5 topCapHeight:bubbleImage.size.height/2];
        [cell addSubview:imgView];
        [cell bringSubviewToFront:txtViewMessage];

        UILabel *lblTimeStamp = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(textFrame.origin.x+2, imgView.frame.size.height+imgView.frame.origin.y, 90, 10)];
        [lblTimeStamp setText:message.dateTime];//set time here
        [lblTimeStamp setFont:FONT_300_LIGHT(7)];
        [lblTimeStamp setTextColor:GET_COLOR_WITH_RGB(129,129,129, 1)];
        [lblTimeStamp setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        [lblTimeStamp setBackgroundColor:[UIColor  clearColor]];
        [cell addSubview:lblTimeStamp];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I need to use in delegate method of JSQMessageviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i didn't get much time to look in to it .. but again you can add that image in same message bubble xib and add constraints according to your need. [Try this xib](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wy0125yrln97wu4/JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming.xib%202.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

How I add custom Label in JSQMessageviewcontroller is... 
I declare **Label** text before ViewDidLoad.

```
 // Add Text Label
let myLabel: UILabel = {
    let lb = UILabel()
    lb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    lb.textAlignment = .center
    lb.numberOfLines = 1
    lb.textColor = UIColor.white
    lb.font=UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
    lb.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green:70.0/255.0, blue:110.0/255.0, alpha:1)
    lb.text = NSLocalizedString("No Notification", comment: "")

    return lb
}()
```

And add this code in viewDidiLoad or call anywhere you like.

```
 self.view.addSubview(myLabel)
 setUpMyLabel()
```

This is how I add custom label in my app. Hope this will help you. :)