# Change position of Avatar in JSQMessageViewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Can we able to change the postion of avatar / profile image from bottom to top similar to skype in single thread page.
Note: Github also follows the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have maintain separate cell xibs. You just need to do changes in those xibs, also need to add new constraints according to your need.
[Use this xib](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dzar4jrb8vw0uyy/JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming.xib.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Thanks kavya for answer. But when I update the constraint, it was ok for 4 liner. but avatar image is not visible for single liner message. Did you done this previously?

Comment: @AbhishekJain  I have added link of xib in my answer. Use this xib for reference.

Comment: Thanks a ton Kavya !! It work like a charm. I already accepted your answer. Can you please look into this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097256/add-custom-label-in-jsqviewmessageviewcontroller-ios/33098276#33098276 another query of JSQMessageViewController.

Comment: @ kavya Did you get the chance to review above link.

Comment: @AbhishekJain Sorry i didn't get much time to look in to it .. but again you can add that image in same message bubble xib and add constraints according to your need.